# gnome-terminal can't set 256 color support correctly with or without tmux

Tags: bash, 14.10, gnome-terminal, zsh, tmux

I've been trying to set up 256 color support correctly for quite some time but it seems to never work for me so I'm not even remotely sure what I'm doing wrong.

How it looks in the terminal vs gVIM:

[image]

What I've tried so far, and just in case I use zsh (also tried with bash)

- added export TERM=xterm-256color, the screenshot is the current outcome of it.
- then changed it to TERM=gnome-256color, same outcome
- then changed it to TERM=screen-256color (this was so I could use `tmux`, and yes I used `tmux -2` and added the `set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"` to `.tmux.conf`. Same outcome.
- added `set t_Co=256` to `.vimrc`, same outcome.

It's been really frustrating. I'm just not sure if I need to install additional packages or something.

Comment: What is the output of `tput colors`

Comment: And another test: https://github.com/l0b0/xterm-color-count

Comment: Related: http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/1890/205

Comment: TERM should be xterm-256color outside of tmux, and screen-256color inside tmux.

Answer (score 4):

Just to leave the answer here to those who are still chasing this. I guess I have learned my lesson in misunderstanding 256 color support in a way.

So I found my answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/544857/vim-color-scheme-not-showing-up-properly-in-mountain-lions-terminal-app). To sum it up, themes like [Gotham](https://github.com/whatyouhide/vim-gotham) offers 256 support, and I had in mind that it would go both ways in terms of appearances (terminal and gui). This is not the case of course, one would have to use gVim (you can get it with `apt-get install vim-gtk`) to use themes like Gotham.

Another answer by [visit_muc](http://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/33fn2f/help_gnometerminal_cant_set_256_color_support/cqklvd7) in reddit:

> You also need to understand, that the terminal will never look 100%
>   like gvim. Most vim themes consist of two color schemes. One for vim
>   (256 color) and one for gvim (24bit Truecolor HTML codes).

Comment: Please accept your own answer to close the post.

Comment: @Helio I can't yet, gotta wait four hours till it allows me.